# windows 8 + Jdk 6 + Apache Tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, windows-8, jdk6

I have project running on Windows 7 ,jdk6 and Apache tomcat7 and eclipse juno.

Now I have to move it to the windows8.

In windows8, I have downloaded the jdk1.6.0_35 for 64-bit windows,Apche-tomcat7 for 64 bit and eclipse luna.

but when I run this project it will give me jsp compilation errors and also give me following error

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:661)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

root cause

```
java.io.IOException: tmpFile.renameTo(classFile) failed
org.apache.jasper.compiler.SmapUtil$SDEInstaller.install(SmapUtil.java:204)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.SmapUtil.installSmap(SmapUtil.java:163)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:483)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

What should i do to resolve this error in windows8 ?

Comment: It's compiled a .jsp to a classfile. The classfile is a tmp file, I suspect, and the compiler doesn't have the privileges to rename it to a .class file in the right dir. So under what account are you running and does it have rights to write to the directory the webapp's installed in?

Comment: User which I logged in with Admin only.I had moved this webapps to windows7 and windowsNT there it is also giving the same compilation errors...

Comment: Does your jsp file throw a FileNotFoundException perhaps? https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=38713

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Disable McAfee anti-virus real-time scanning.